# Uniqueness and continuous dependence on the data of Heat equation.

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, heat-equation, gronwall-type-inequality

Let two smooth $v_1$ and $v_2$ both satisfy the system

$$\partial_t{v}-\Delta v=f \quad \text{in} \quad U \times (0,\infty), $$
$$v = g \quad \text{on} \quad \partial U \times (0,\infty),$$

for some fixed given smooth $f: \bar{U}\times (0,\infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $g: \partial U \times (0,\infty).$ $U$ is open, bounded and $U \subset \mathbb{R}^n.$ Show that
$$\sup_{x \in U}  |v_1(t, x) − v_2(t, x)| \rightarrow 0,$$
as $t \rightarrow \infty.$

This is my work:

Let $ u =v_1 -v_2,$ it is sufficient to prove $\sup_{x \in U}  |u(x,t)| \rightarrow 0,$
as $t \rightarrow \infty. (1)$

$u$ obeys the system
$$\partial_t{u}-\Delta u=0 \quad \text{in} \quad U \times (0,\infty), $$
$$u = 0 \quad \text{on} \quad \partial U \times (0,\infty).$$
Multiply both sides by $u.|u|^{2(m-1)},$ note that $\partial_t(|u|^{2m})=2m\partial_tu.u.|u|^{2(m-1)}$ then
$$\dfrac{1}{2m}\partial_t\int_{U}|u|^{2m}dx=\int_{U}\Delta u.u.|u|^{2(m-1)}dx$$
Apply integration by part for the RHS, we get
$$\dfrac{1}{2m}\partial_t\int_{U}|u|^{2m}dx=-(2m-1)\int_{U}|\nabla u|^2|u|^{2(m-1)}dx.$$
By the generalize Poincare's inequality, we obtain
$$\partial_t\int_{U}|u|^{2m}dx \leq -2C\left(2-\dfrac{1}{m}\right)\int_{U}|u|^{2m}dx$$
or $$\partial_t\Vert u(t,\cdot)\Vert^{2m}_{L^{2m}(U)} \leq -2C\left(2-\dfrac{1}{m}\right)\Vert u(t,\cdot)\Vert^{2m}_{L^{2m}(U)}$$
$\Rightarrow 2m \Vert u(t,\cdot)\Vert^{2m-1}.\partial_t\Vert u(t,\cdot)\Vert_{L^{2m}(U)} \leq  -2C\left(2-\dfrac{1}{m}\right)\Vert u(t,\cdot)\Vert^{2m}_{L^{2m}(U)}$

$\Rightarrow \partial_t\Vert u(t,\cdot)\Vert_{L^{2m}(U)} \leq -2\dfrac{C}{m}\left(2-\dfrac{1}{m}\right)\Vert u(t,\cdot)\Vert_{L^{2m}(U)}$

Applying Gronwall's inequality, we get

$\Vert u(t,\cdot)\Vert_{L^{2m}(U)} \leq e^{-2\frac{C}{m}\left(2-\frac{1}{m}\right)t}\Vert u(0,\cdot)\Vert_{L^{2m}(U)}.$

I am planing to let $m \rightarrow \infty$ to obtain $\Vert u(t,\cdot)\Vert_{L^{\infty}(U)}$  and let $t \rightarrow \infty$ then $e^{-2\frac{C}{m}\left(2-\frac{1}{m}\right)t} \rightarrow 0$ to obtain (1). But the problem is as $m \rightarrow \infty,$ $e^{-2\frac{C}{m}\left(2-\frac{1}{m}\right)t} \rightarrow 1 \neq 0.$

Am I on the right track or did I make some wrong steps?

Could you provide any ideas to improve my work?

Comment: More details about $U$ please: Bounded? in $\mathbb{R}$? in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Comment: $U $ is open, bounded and $U  \subset \mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: You do not want to expand the solution as an eigenfunction series? It seems the most direct way to prove this.

Comment: In my class, we still haven't studied about eigenfunction series. We only start studying Heat equations via the Energy method.

Comment: Where is the initial condition?

Comment: @MatthewCassell - This is true for general initial conditions and therefore it is not mentioned

Comment: @dtttruc I apologize. It seems more tricky than I first thought. Can you use anything else? Maybe maximum principle? Arzelà–Ascoli theorem might help since you have $L_p$ convergence and you want uniform convergence.

Comment: @MOMO I think if we apply the maximum principle, we can only claim $\sup_{x \in U}|u(t,x)|$ be bounded by $\sup |u(0,x)|,$ but we have no clue that $\sup |u(0,x)| = 0?$ and why do you want uniform convergence? Could you tell me more? Thank you very much for your response.

Comment: @dtttruc It is not what I want. You asked to show $\sup_x|u|\rightarrow 0$ as $t\rightarrow\infty$ which is the definition for uniform convergence. In your accepted answer, it is shown that $E=||u||^2\rightarrow 0$ which is convergence in $L^2$ norm. But this is something you already managed to prove in your post... (for $m=1$)

Comment: @MOMO Oh now I got your idea, If we have the convergence in $L^2$ norm, it is not sufficient to get the convergence in $L^{\infty}$ norm, which I tried to prove in my original work, is it? Moreover, if we have $u(x,t) \rightarrow 0,$ it is also not enough to conclude $lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} sup_{x} |u(x,t)|=0.$

Comment: @dtttruc Right. $L^2$ convergence does not imply $L^\infty$ convergence. Even $L^p$ convergence for all $p>0$ (which is close to what you showed) does not imply $L^\infty$ convergence. When you claim $u(x,t)→0$ you need to specify for which $x$ you mean. Generaly this not not true for any (or even almost any) $x$. What you can conclude by $L^2$ convergence is an existence of subsequence $u(x,t_n)$ that converges for almost any $x$ to $0$

Comment: @dtttruc By using the maximum principle you might get the conditions for Arzelà–Ascoli theorem in order to show uniform convergence.

Comment: @MOMO But, $u$ being the solution of the heat equation gives it certain smoothness properties, so I don't think it is possible that $u(t_n,x)\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$ without $u(t,x)\to 0$ in general, am I wrong?

Comment: Maybe, but even so $u→0$ does not guarantee $\sup|u|→0$. Anyway, you should be careful when assuming anything about the smoothness of $u$, because as far as I know one can show this by finding the solution as an eigenfunction series, but you did not want to rely on this.

Comment: @dtttruc Sorry for taking so long on this. It ended up being a bit more delicate than I expected.

Comment: Please have a look at my edited answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as mentioned in the comments, the energy energy integral is useful here. Let $u$ be defined as in the question.

Define

$$E(t)=\int_{U}{u(t,x)}^2~\mathrm d^m x$$
Note $E$ is bounded below by $0$.

Now, observe
$$\dot E(t)=\int_U 2 ~u(t,x)~\partial_tu(t,x)~\mathrm d^m x \\ =2\int_U (u ~\Delta u)(t,x)\mathrm d^mx \\ =2\int_U \big(u ~\nabla\cdot( \nabla u)\big)(t,x)\mathrm d^mx$$

Recall the generalized integration by parts:
$$\int_U \phi~\nabla\cdot v~\mathrm d\mu^m=\int_{\partial U}n\cdot \phi v~\mathrm d\mu^{n-1}-\int_{U}v\cdot \nabla\phi~\mathrm d\mu^m$$

Taking in our case $\phi=u$ and $v=\nabla u$, we get
$$\dot E(t)=2\int_U \big(u ~\nabla\cdot( \nabla u)\big)(t,x)\mathrm d^mx \\ =2\int_{\partial U} \big( n\cdot (u\nabla u)\big)(t,x)\mathrm d^m x-2\int_U |\nabla u|^2(t,x)\mathrm d^m x$$
The first integral is zero due to the assumptions on the boundary data of $u$, and therefore we obtain
$$\dot E(t)=-2\int_U|\nabla u|^2(t,x)\mathrm d^m x$$

Poincare's inequality implies

$$\dot E(t)=-2\int_U |\nabla u|^2\mathrm d^m x=2{\left\Vert\nabla u(t,\cdot)\right\Vert_2}^2\leq -2C {\Vert u(t,\cdot)\Vert_2}^2$$
Since ${\Vert u(t,\cdot)\Vert_2}^2=E$, we have
$$\dot E\leq -2C E$$
Hence by Gronwall's inequality we get $E(t)\leq \mathrm e^{-2Ct}E(0)$ which implies $E\to 0 $ which implies ${\Vert u(t,\cdot)\Vert_2}\to 0$ as $t\to\infty$.

---

So, we have shown that $\Vert u(t,\cdot)\Vert_2\to 0$, but this is not enough to show that $\Vert u(t,\cdot)\Vert_\infty\to 0$, as desired in the question. However, this is rectified using the **strong maximum principle.**

Define the parabolic cylinder and its boundary
$$U(T):=(0,T]\times U \\ \Gamma(T)=\overline{U(T)}\setminus U(T)=(\{0\}\times \bar U)\cup ([0,T]\times\partial U)$$

> **THEOREM:** *Strong maximum principle for the heat equation*.
> Assume $u$ is a classical solution of the heat equation in $U(T)$. Then, (i)
> $$\max_{\overline{U(T)}}u=\max_{\Gamma(T)}u$$
> Furthermore (ii), if $U$ is connected and there exists a point $(t_0,x_0)\in U(T)$ such that $u(t_0,x_0)=\max_{\overline{U(T)}}u$, then $u$ is constant in $\overline{U(t_0)}$.

(For proof: See page 55 of Evans PDE book.)

The (ii) statement means that, if ever $u$ assumes its maximum inside $U$ at any positive time, then $u$ must be constant.

In our case, we know that $u=0$ on $\partial U$. That means that, aside from the trivial case $u\equiv 0$, we know that
$$\operatorname{argmax}_{\overline{U(T)}}|u|\in \{0\}\times U$$
I.e, it must occur in the open domain $U$ at $t=0$. However, the (ii) statement of the above theorem now tells us that , aside from the trivial solution $u\equiv 0$, for all times $t>0$,
$$\sup_U |u(t,\cdot)| < \sup_U |u(0,\cdot)|$$
Because otherwise , $u$ would be constant in the domain $U(t)$, and we know the only constant solution satisfying our BCs is the zero solution. So, we have shown that the function
$$M(t)=\sup_{U}|u(t,\cdot)|$$
Is a decreasing function bounded below by zero, and hence $M\to M_\infty\in\mathbb R_{\geq 0}$.

---

To show $M_\infty=0$ is a little bit more difficult. But essentially, the idea is, the only way for $\Vert u(t,\cdot)\Vert _2\to 0$ (as already shown) while maintaining $\Vert u(t,\cdot)\Vert_\infty \to M_\infty >0$ would be if the family of functions $u(t,\cdot)$ "clustered" around some finite collection of points $\{x_0,x_1,...x_{N-1}\}$, i.e $u(t,x)\to 0$ as $t\to\infty$ for all $x\in U\setminus \{x_0,...,x_{N-1}\}$ but with $u(t,x)\to L\leq M_\infty$ for all $x\in \{x_0,...,x_{N-1}\}$.

However, such "clustering" is impossible, as it would violate the smoothing properties of the heat equation. To make the proof easier, assume that only one "cluster point" $x_0$ exists satisfying $\Vert u(t,x_0) \Vert_\infty\to M_\infty>0$. **Since we already know that** ($\star$) $u(t,x)\to 0$ as $t\to\infty$ $\forall x\neq x_0$, this means that, given $t$ large enough and $\epsilon$ small enough, we can make the derivative estimate

$(\star) ~:~ \text{proof needed!}$
$$\left|\frac{u(t,x_0+\epsilon\upsilon)-u(t,x_0)}{\epsilon}\right| \\ (\upsilon \in \mathbb R^m , |\upsilon|=1)$$
Arbitrarily large. But, by the mean value theorem, we know that $\exists x^*$ on the line segment connecting $x_0$ and $x_0+\epsilon\upsilon$ such that
$$\upsilon \cdot \nabla u(t,x^*)=\frac{u(t,x_0+\epsilon\upsilon)-u(t,x_0)}{\epsilon}$$
Which implies
$$|\upsilon \cdot \nabla u(t,x^*)|=|\nabla u(t,x^*)|=\left|\frac{u(t,x_0+\epsilon\upsilon)-u(t,x_0)}{\epsilon}\right|$$
And since we know we can make the RHS arbitrarily large, that means we can make $|\nabla u(t,x^*)|$ arbitrarily large as long as we choose a point $x^*$ close enough to $x_0$ and a time $t$ large enough. However, we know from theorem 9 on page 61 of Evans PDE that $\exists c\in\mathbb R_+$ such that
$$\max_{C(t,x;r/2)}|\nabla u|\leq \frac{c}{r^{m+3}}\Vert u \Vert_{L^1\big(C(t,x;r)\big)}$$
Where $C(t,x;r)$ is the cylinder
$$C(t,x;r)=\{(s,y)\in\mathbb R_{\geq 0}\times\mathbb R^m : |x-y|\leq r ~\text{and}~t-r^2\leq s\leq t\}$$

But, [since $L^2$ convergence implies $L^1$ convergence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1529156/uniform-convergence-implies-l2-convergence-and-l2-convergence-implies-l1) we know that $\Vert u \Vert_{L^1\big(C(t,x;r)\big)}\to 0$ as $t\to\infty$, and thus our ability to make $|\nabla u|$ arbitrarily large would violate our initial assumptions. Therefore, it is not possible for the families of functions $u(t,\cdot)$ to "cluster" around a point $x_0$ and therefore the only possible value for $M_\infty$ is $0$, in other words,

$$\boxed{\Vert u(t,\cdot)\Vert_\infty\to 0~~\text{as}~t\to\infty}$$

As desired. $\blacksquare$.

---

**Addendum:** Details.

The key point is to show that $\Vert u \Vert_{L^1\big(C^1(t,x;r)\big)}\to 0$ as $t\to\infty$. We already know that $E(t)={\Vert u(t,\cdot) \Vert_2}^2\leq \mathrm e^{-2Ct}E(0)$ from Gronwall's inequality. This means that, for any $0<T<t$, we have
$$\sqrt{\int_{t-T}^{t}{E(t')}^2\mathrm dt}=\Vert u \Vert_{L^2\big(U(t)\setminus U(t-T)\big)}\to 0 ~~\text{as}~t\to\infty$$
But, since $C(t,x;\sqrt{T})\subset \big(U(t)\setminus U(t-T)\big)$ which implies $\Vert u \Vert_{L^2\big(C(t,x;\sqrt{T})\big)}\to 0$ as $t\to\infty$ for all positive $T$. But, since $L^2$ convergence implies $L^1$ convergence, we get $\Vert u \Vert_{L^1\big(C(t,x;r)\big)}\to 0 $ as $t\to\infty$ for any $x\in U$ and suitable $r>0$.

Comment: By showing $E\rightarrow 0$ you showed $L_2$ convergence, but uniform convergence is needed here.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I can prove $E \rightarrow 0,$ but how does it help to prove $u(x,t) \rightarrow 0?$ And sorry, what do you mean by $E_{\infty},$ is it $lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} E(t)$ or does it have any special properties? And why $\partial_t u \rightarrow 0?$

Comment: @MOMO I don't see why uniform convergence is required here.

Comment: @dtttruc $E\to 0\implies u\to 0$ since $u^2 \geq 0$. Yes, $E_\infty = \lim_{t\to\infty }E(t)$ . We know $\partial_t u\to 0$ because, $E\to E_\infty$ implies that $\dot E\to 0$, and $\dot{E}=2\int_U u\partial_t u \mathrm d\mu^n $ which means either $u\to 0$ (which is equivalent) or $\dot u\to 0$.

Comment: Thank you very much, I got it ^^. For the second part $E \rightarrow E_{\infty}$ implying $\dot{E} \rightarrow 0,$ at first I thought we must have conditions $E$ converges uniformly to $E_{\infty}$ to conclude $\dot{E} \rightarrow 0$ but I checked these conditions work for sequence not for the real function, is it? I also will write an alternative proof using $E \rightarrow 0.$

Comment: @K.defaoite see my comment on the original post.

Comment: @dtttruc It should be reasonably easy to show that $E$ is a smooth function of $t$, which forces that $E\to E_\infty$ implies $\dot E\to 0$.

Comment: @K.defaoite But I am not sure if we have the convergence of $L^2$ to imply the convergence pointwise of $u(x,t).$ Could you prove it? Furtheremore, as MOMO said, it is not sufficient from $u
(x,t) \rightarrow 0$ to conclude $\sup_{x}|u(x,t)| \rightarrow 0.$

Comment: @dtttruc I will come back to this tomorrow.

Comment: @K.defaoite I have two questions, could you explain to me? Firstly, can you explain clearly that why if $I(t,\varepsilon) \rightarrow 0$ as $t \rightarrow \infty,$ then the derivative estimate is arbitrary large? 
Secondly, for the $L^2$ convergence implies $L^1$ convergence, we are considering the convergence of $u$ in $L^2(U)$ w.r.t $x$, but why we can conclude the convergence of $u$ in $L^1$ with another set $C(t,x,r)$ w.r.t $(x,t)$ ?

Comment: @dtttruc Perhaps the usage of an integral was not the best way to go about it. The ability to make the derivative estimate arbitrarily large follows from the fact that $u(t,x)\to 0$ as $t\to\infty$ for all $x\neq x_0$.

Comment: As for the other point, we already know that $\Vert u \Vert_{L^2(C(t,x;r))}\to 0$ as $t\to\infty$. We know this because (1) we can simply integrate $E$ over some interval $(t,t+T)$ and let $t\to\infty$ to conclude that $\Vert 
 u\Vert_{L^2\big(U(T+t)\setminus U(t)\big)}\to 0$ as $t\to\infty$. Then (2) we observe that $C(t+T,x;r)\subset U(t+T)\setminus U(t)$ for a suitable choice of $r$, and use the fact that $L^2$ convergence on an open domain $\Omega$ implies $L^2$ convergence on all sub-domains $\Omega'\subseteq \Omega$.

Comment: @K.defaoite Sorry but can you explain why we have $u(x,t) \rightarrow 0$ as $t \rightarrow \infty$ for all $x \neq x_0$? For the second part  why when $E(t) \rightarrow 0$ then we can conclude that $\int_{t}^{t+T}E(t) \rightarrow 0$? Can you prove it. I have a counter-example, if we consider that $u(x,t)=\sqrt{\dfrac{|sint|}{|t|}}.f(x)$ then $E(t)= \int_{U}u^2(x,t)dx \rightarrow 0$ but $\int_{t}^{t+T}\int_U u^2(x,t)dxdt$ does not converge to $0.$

Comment: @dtttruc Sorry, this follows from the fact that $E(t)\leq \mathrm e^{-2Ct}E(0)$ as given from Gronwall's inequality, not from the fact that $E(t)\to 0$. I'll edit.

Comment: @dtttruc Note that the fact that $U$ is bounded is important here - otherwise the assertion that $L^2$ convergence implies $L^1$ convergence would not hold.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clear details, it makes sense now for the second part. But sorry for the first part that $u(x,t) \rightarrow 0$ as $t \rightarrow \infty$ for all $x \neq x_0$ , you haven't explained to me yet. This is because I can find an example that L^2 convergence does not imply pointwise convergence. Furthermore, if we only assume there exist $x_0$ such that $u(t,x_0) \rightarrow M_{\infty} >0$, it is not sufficient to get $u(x,t) \rightarrow 0$ as $t \rightarrow \infty$ for all $x \neq x_0$.

Comment: @dtttruc I believe that $L^2$ convergence of a sequence of continuous functions does indeed imply pointwise convergence a.e , I will try to find a reference

Comment: @K.defaoite This is what I found for the sequence of continuous functions that converge in $L^2$ but not converge pointwise. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/372720/do-l2-convergence-and-continuity-imply-pointwise-convergence

Comment: @dtttruc Yes, it is possible for a sequence of continuous functions which converge in $L^2$ to not converge pointwise. However, for the purposes of this problem, only pointwise convergence **almost everywhere** is required, which I believe is guaranteed.

Comment: @dtttruc  Proven! Have a look at my other answer.

Answer (score 1):

To fix the gap $(\star)$ in my previous answer.

In my other answer, I claimed that $\Vert u(t,\cdot)\Vert_2\to 0$ as $t\to\infty$ implied that $u(t,x)\to 0$ for *almost all* $x\in U$.

Note that the restriction to "almost all" is necessary, because $L^p$ convergence does not imply everywhere pointwise convergence, [not even for a sequence of continuous functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/372720/do-l2-convergence-and-continuity-imply-pointwise-convergence). However, we can fix this, with the help of the following theorem:

> **THEOREM:** *Rapid* convergence in measure implies pointwise convergence almost everywhere.

> Let $(X,\Sigma,\mu)$ be a measure space and let $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ be a sequence of measurable functions which converges *in measure* to the measurable function $f$. Then, as shown by John Dawkins [HERE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2152410/when-does-convergence-in-measure-imply-convergence-almost-everywhere) as a consequence of the Borel-Cantelli lemma, if
> $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu\big(\{x\in X:|f_n(x)-f(x)|>\epsilon\}\big)<\infty \\ \forall \epsilon>0$$
> Then, $f_n\overset{\text{p.w}}{\longrightarrow}f$ almost everywhere as $n\to\infty$.

---

In our case, we can consider the measure space $(U,\mathscr B(U),\mu^m)$ where $\mathscr B(U)$ are the Borel subsets of $U$ and $\mu^m$ is the $m$ dimensional standard Euclidean measure. [Since $L^p$ convergence implies convergence in measure](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1281421/convergence-in-lp-implies-convergence-in-measure), we know that $u_k\overset{\mu^m}{\longrightarrow} 0$ as $k\to\infty$ where $u_k=u(t_k,\cdot)$ is the function $u$ evaluated at time $t=t_k$, and $(t_k)_{k\in\mathbb N}$ is any strictly increasing sequence of positive real numbers.

First, observe that
$$\text{IF}~~{\Vert u(t,\cdot )\Vert^2_{L^2(U)}}=\int_U {u(t,x)}^2\mathrm d^m x<\delta \\ \text{THEN}~~\mu^m\big(x\in U:{|u(t,x)|}^2>\epsilon\big)< \frac{\delta}{\epsilon} \\ \text{equivalently,}~~~\mu^m\big(x\in U:|u(t,x)|>\epsilon\big)< \frac{\delta}{\epsilon^2}$$

I.e, if ${\Vert u(t,\cdot )\Vert^2_{L^2(U)}}$ is less than $\delta$, then ${u(t,\cdot)}^2$ can only take values of $\epsilon$ or greater on a set $V\subset U$ with measure $\mu^m(V)$ no larger than $\delta/\epsilon$.

Now, recall our Gronwall inequality:
$$\int_U {u(t,x)}^2\mathrm d^m x={\Vert u(t,\cdot )\Vert^2_{L^2(U)}}=E(t)\leq \mathrm e^{-2c_1 t}E(0)$$
Putting the above two together, we get

$${\Vert u(t,\cdot )\Vert^2_{L^2(U)}}<\mathrm e^{-2c_1 t}E(0)\implies \mu^m\big(x\in U:|u(t,x)|>\epsilon\big)< \frac{\mathrm e^{-2c_1 t}E(0)}{\epsilon^2}$$
And therefore, letting $t=t_k$,

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \mu^m(x\in U:|u_k(x)|>\epsilon) < \frac{E(0)}{\epsilon^2}\sum_{k=1}^\infty \mathrm e^{-2c_1k}<\infty$$

Thus $u_k\overset{\text{p.w}}{\longrightarrow} 0$ almost everywhere as $k\to\infty$. Since this holds for any sequence $(t_k)_{k\in\infty}$ we conclude that $u(t,x)\overset{\text{p.w}}{\longrightarrow} 0$ as $t\to
\infty$ for almost all $x\in U$. My other answer uses this as a starting point to show that this "almost all" is in fact, all.